# Command option to ignore errors during drush dl <list of modules>

Tags: drush

Just trying to start creating prefab lists (of modules etc.) and building my site development environment at the moment. I'm trying to call `sudo drush dl (list of modules)` and it works until it can't find one and stops the entire process.

Is there a switch I can use to get drush to continue through the list and perhaps even list the terms which failed to download (not important). I've just seen a sentence alluding to creating your own drush commands, but figured I'd check the community first as that could take a big chunk of scarce time!

Thank you for contributing to this great site, hopefully one day I can return the favour!

Comment: This is really a Bash question, and therefore off topic for this forum.  There is a special Bash variable you can set to allow processing to continue; I did a brief search for it, and did not find it. Wade through `man bash`, and you'll find it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, today I realised bash is going to be important soon. I'll check that out. I found my answer playing around with drush yesterday, so will add the answer now

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... Found out how to work around such a situation:

By skipping the explicit download function `dl` and just using the enable `en`command

`cd module path`

drush en **file list**

you get an automatic download option, which I think by adding -y you can automatically answer yes to all pompts. It's just a problem that sometimes the module names won't always match the package name.